# Difference between profiling and dignostics(performance counters and monitoring)

Tags: performance, profiling, monitoring, performancecounter, diagnostics

I am working on implementing prototype performance monitoring system, I went through multiple documents and resources for understanding the concept but am still confused between profiling and dignostics. Can somebody provide an explanation of these two terms, their relation and when/where do we use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Profiling" usually means mapping things happening in the system (e.g., performance monitoring events) to processes, or to functions (or instructions) within processes.  Examples of profiling tools in the Unix/Linux world include "gprof" and "oprofile".  Intel's "VTune Amplifier" is another commonly used profiler.  Some profilers are limited to looking at the performance of a single process, while others (usually requiring elevated privileges) monitor all processes (including the kernel) operating on the system during the measurement period.

"Diagnostics" is not a term I see very often in performance monitoring, but from the context I would assume that this means looking for evidence of "trouble" in the overall operation of the system.  As an example, the performance monitoring system at https://github.com/TACC/tacc_stats collects hardware and software performance monitoring data on each server.  In TACC's operation, the data is reviewed automatically to look for matches to a variety of heuristics related to known patterns of poor performance (e.g., all memory accesses being made to one socket in a 2-socket system).  The data is also used by human performance analysts in response to user queries and is aggregated to provide an overview of performance-related characteristics by application area.